# SIngle Page Application - Angular2 & ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, angular, api, single-page-application

I've a question for an application I want to develop. This is a custom e-commerce platform, and I try to show the visitors how many other people are viewing the page right now.

How can I do this using Angular2 and a .NET API ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: This is for traffic stats.. I want to show real-time stats of people currently viewing the page.

Comment: The scope of the question is pretty wide. You should break down into small problems and try to resolve those. For ex. How would you count the currently online visitors, how would you retrieve them and at last how would you display them in angular 2.

Comment: you should use google analytics for that, there is no point to bother of coding that logic yourself unless you have a some sort of unique use case that google analytics cant handle.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is client-side only and runs in the browser for ONE user. So it would have no way to know which other uses are using the application or count them.

You would have to do some type of counting on the server side. You could then have that number accessible via ASP.NET Web API or some other REST-ful service.

The Angular app can then retrieve the value using Http and display it.